# Rails dding new related records with simple form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I have a Rails (paltformatec) simple_form input form in which I want to include records from a related model - I have seen association but I want to create new records rather than select one

I have the form to enter new people - where I have render I want to be able to input one or more family members into a related table: I believe I will need javascript or coffeescript to allow for a variable number of family members to be create but I can't even get one. Below is a portion of the form

```
= f.input  :zip, :label => 'Zip', :input_html => { :class => "span1" }
= f.input  :phone, :label => 'Phone', :input_html => { :class => "span2" }
= f.input  :spouse, :label => 'Spouse'
= render  'family_members/form'
```

This is my family members form where I would like to add one or more people:

```
= simple_form_for :family_members do |f|
= f.input :name
= f.input :relation
= f.input :age
= f.input :encrypted_ssn
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [cocoon](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon) (it has example for simple_form) or [awesome_nested_fields](https://github.com/lailsonbm/awesome_nested_fields) (bit more complex but more flexible).